# Obter valor máximo, médio e minimo em um JSON de um array com objetos

Tags: javascript, json, array

Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```js
{
    "funcionarios":[
        {
            "id": 0,
            "nome": "Marcelo",
            "sobrenome": "Silva",
            "salario": 3200.00,
            "area": "SM"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Washington",
            "sobrenome": "Ramos",
            "salario": 2700.00,
            "area": "UD"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "Sergio",
            "sobrenome": "Pinheiro",
            "salario": 2450.00,
            "area": "SD"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "nome": "Bernardo",
            "sobrenome": "Costa",
            "salario": 3700.00,
            "area": "SM"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "nome": "Cleverton",
            "sobrenome": "Farias",
            "salario": 2750.00,
            "area": "SD"
        }
    ]
}
```

Para conseguir o salário mínimo e máximo utilizei a seguinte função:

```
function sortByAttribute(arr, attribute) {
    return arr.sort(function(a, b){
        return a[attribute] - b[attribute];
});
```

Em euqe depois eu armazeno o retorno da função em um *array* e retiro o primeiro índice como sendo o menor salário e o último índice sendo o maior salário. Porém agora preciso calcular a média dos salários. Como posso fazer isso? Não tenho ideia.

Comment: Qual código você já tentou fazer para calcular essa média?

Comment: Cara sua função da usando o `sort`, então na verdade você ta ordenando, para você saber o mínimo ou máximo você vai ter que percorrer seu json ou seu array, o que você fez para calcular a média ?

Comment: Dica: se você sabe como calcular médias e sabe como fazer um loop em js, o problema está resolvido. Qual dessas coisas você não sabe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar um laço `for` para somar todos os salários e depois dividir esse total pelo número de registros. Assim:

```js
const lista = [
  { nome: 'Marcelo', salario: 3200.0 },
  { nome: 'Washington', salario: 2700.0 },
  { nome: 'Sergio', salario: 2450.0 },
  { nome: 'Bernardo', salario: 3700.0 },
  { nome: 'Cleverton', salario: 2750.0 }
];

let total = 0;

for (const item of lista) {
  total += item.salario;
}

const media = total / lista.length;

console.log(media);
```

Se você preferir uma opção um pouco mais declarativa, pode usar o `reduce` também:

```js
const lista = [
  { nome: 'Marcelo', salario: 3200.0 },
  { nome: 'Washington', salario: 2700.0 },
  { nome: 'Sergio', salario: 2450.0 },
  { nome: 'Bernardo', salario: 3700.0 },
  { nome: 'Cleverton', salario: 2750.0 }
];

const total = lista.reduce((total, item) => total + item.salario, 0);
const media = total / lista.length;

console.log(media);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function media(array){
    var somaDosSalarios = 0;

  array.forEach( item => somaDosSalarios+=item.salario);

  return somaDosSalarios / array.length;
}


console.log(media(json.funcionarios));
```